# Why I am I getting Error: incompatible types (from S4 to double) in subassignment type fix in my R code?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to do a hypothesis test via bootstrapping for a mixed effects logistic regression. I'm using a data frame with columns for participant, tone, word, correctness, and background, and changing a column called boot_correct with the bootstrapped data of each iteration. In the for loop at the end, I keep getting the error:

```
  incompatible types (from S4 to double) in subassignment type fix"
```

The glmr() function works fine with the original data frame before I add the boot_correct column.

Any idea where this error is coming from?

```
set.seed(1865)
n <- length(ptc_data$correct)
n
B <- 100
variable <- ptc_data$correct

BootstrapSamples <- matrix(sample(c(ptc_data$correct), size=n*B, replace=TRUE),
                                   nrow=n, ncol=B)

Boot.test.stat.word <- rep(0,B)
boot_data <- data
boot_data$boot_correct <- BootstrapSamples[1:304,1]

for (i in 1:B){
  boot_data$boot_correct <- BootstrapSamples[1:304,i]
  boot_data$boot_correct[boot_data$boot_correct  == 1]  <-  0
  boot_data$boot_correct[boot_data$boot_correct  == 2]  <-  1
  Boot.test.stat.word[i] <- glmer(boot_correct ~ background + word +
                                (1 | participant), data = boot_data, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
                              nAGQ = 10)
}
```

Comment: You are trying to assing a object of class merMod , which is returned by `glmer` to a numeric vector. This can't work. You could store your models in a list.

Comment: Replace `Boot.test.stat.word <- rep(0,B)` with `Boot.test.stat.word <- list()` and rerun your code. This should fix your problem.

Comment: You would also need to change to `Boot.test.stat.word[[i]] <- glmer(...)` with double brackets for the list.